# qbittorrent download speed affected by upload speed limit

Tags: download, bittorrent, speed, upload, qbittorrent

When I set the global upload speed limit to 3KiB/sec, the download speed is about 100~300 KiB/sec, but I changed the upload speed limit to 30 KiB/sec, then the download speed increased to 5~8 MiB/sec.

Is this normal? Is there an 'minimum' upload speed limit that does not limit the download speed limit?

Comment: It is normal. Some people limit the download speed they will give to leechers ...

Comment: Consider that you must send (upload) requests and ACKs whenever you download data...

Comment: BitTorrent clients use a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tit_for_tat#Peer-to-peer_file_sharing algorithm and choke peers that aren't uploading anything (i.e. you with 3KB/s).

Comment: @grawity "sending request" (to download something) and "uploading my data" are different

Comment: @IvanKozik  So what's the rule? Is there a formula for download limit - upload limit?

Comment: In the previous version of qbittorrent, I don't think there is such a limit, but it happens when I upgraded it to qbittorrent 4.0.0. Furthremore, in another torrent client, it limits the download speed to some limit when I set upload limit (and I can see the limit in the setting). But in qbittorrent 4.0, I can't see anything and there seems to be no download limit, but there really exists actual download limit. This is what I don't understand.